# lookahead and lookbehind in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I want to print before and after 10 words of the matched word in the string.

For example, I have

```
string = "About the company -Our client is one of the world's fastest-growing AI-based contract management solution providers.Exp -7+ Years Location -MumbaiJob Role -Min 7years hands-on experience in Natural Language Processing, Machine Learning, Artificial Intelligence, and IBM Watson"
```

In the above string, I want to search of letter experience and wants output like

```
Location -MumbaiJob Role -Min 7years hands-on experience in Natural Language"
```

I tried `(\S+)\s+exp+`, but it only returns one before word.

Comment: lets assume it shows 10 words..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spliting the words on one or more whitespace chracters is probably the best approach:

```
import re

s = "About the company -Our client is one of the world's fastest-growing AI-based contract management solution providers.Exp -7+ Years Location -MumbaiJob Role -Min 7years hands-on experience in Natural Language Processing, Machine Learning, Artificial Intelligence, and IBM Watson"

words = re.split(r'\s+', s)
try:
    index = words.index('experience')
except Exception:
    pass
else:
    start = max(index - 5, 0)
    end = min(index + 6, len(words))
    print(' '.join(words[start:end]))
```

Prints:

```
-MumbaiJob Role -Min 7years hands-on experience in Natural Language Processing, Machine
```

But if you inisist on using a regular expression, then this should print up to 5 words preceding and 5 words following "experience":

```
import re

s = "About the company -Our client is one of the world's fastest-growing AI-based contract management solution providers.Exp -7+ Years Location -MumbaiJob Role -Min 7years hands-on experience in Natural Language Processing, Machine Learning, Artificial Intelligence, and IBM Watson"

m = re.search(r'([\w,;!.+-]+\s+){0,5}experience(\s+[\w,;!.+-]+){0,5}', s)
if m:
    print(m[0])
```

Prints:

```
-MumbaiJob Role -Min 7years hands-on experience in Natural Language Processing, Machine
```

**Update to Handle "experience" or "Experience"**

I have also simplified the regular expression:

```
import re

s = "About the company -Our client is one of the world's fastest-growing AI-based contract management solution providers.Exp -7+ Years Location -MumbaiJob Role -Min 7years hands-on Experience in Natural Language Processing, Machine Learning, Artificial Intelligence, and IBM Watson"

# By splitting on one or more whitespace characters:
words = re.split(r'\s+', s)
try:
    index = words.index('experience')
except Exception:
    try:
        index = words.index('Experience')
    except Exception:
        index = None
if index:
    start = max(index - 5, 0)
    end = min(index + 6, len(words))
    print(' '.join(words[start:end]))


# Using a regular expression:
m = re.search(r'(\S+\s+){0,5}[eE]xperience(\s+\S+){0,5}', s)
if m:
    print(m[0])
```

Prints:

```
-MumbaiJob Role -Min 7years hands-on Experience in Natural Language Processing, Machine
-MumbaiJob Role -Min 7years hands-on Experience in Natural Language Processing, Machine
```

Comment: hi, Thanks for the solution. if you could help me puting codition in this like if i have capital E in experience then it also matches and return output.

Answer (score 1):

you can start by separating your words with spaces, then select from the first 10 words until the end in your list and finally group this list to redo a string

```
 ts=string.split(' ')[10:]
 print(" ".join(ts))
```

Comment: And find the keyword with `idx = ts.index('experience')`

Comment: no i dont want whole sentence, i just want to search for word "experience" in the sentence and print out before and after 10 words of word "experience".

Comment: you can find the index in the list using .index like this then remove 10 elements to the right and to the left  ts[ts.index("experience")-10:ts.index("experience")+10]

Comment: thanks this was helpful @RaphaëlGervillié . if you could help me putiong codition in this like if i have capital E in experience then it also matches and return output

Comment: a way to retrieve the index of the word experience in the wordlist as previously used a loop: for i,j in enumerate(ts):
    if j.lower()=="experience":
        print(i,j)

Answer (score 1):

Please try below regex

```regex
((?:\S+\s){10})(experience)((?:\s\S+){10})
```

Here `\1` will have 10 words before and `\3` will have 10 words after 'experience'

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/i9vjm9/3)